# Savage-Dickey density ratio under horseshoe prior

Tags: regression, bayes-factors

Suppose one has a linear regression with Gaussian noise. The regression coefficients have a horseshoe prior. To test that some regression coefficients equal 0, one applies the Savage-Dickey density ratio test. The problem is that the density of the horseshoe prior is infinity at the zero point. Given that the posterior density at the zero point is finite, would the Savage-Dickey density ratio always support non-zero coefficients? Something should be wrong here. Appreciate if someone can point to some reference on this topic.

Comment: This is the [issue with the Savage-Dickey representation,](https://basepub.dauphine.fr/handle/123456789/4644) namely that it depends on the value of the density on a zero mass set.

Comment: Thank you, Xi'an. I will take a read of the reference. Just some plain reasoning here. There is always the identity p(b)p(y|b) = p(y)p(b|y) where b is the reg coef and y is the reg target (assuming fixed regressors x). The items p(y|b) and p(y) in the identity should be finite. If p(b=0) is infinity, p(b=0|y) has to be infinite to hold the identity. Maybe something like the L'hospital rule is needed to compute the ratio p(b=0|y)/p(b=0)...